# NLTK import error

Tags: windows, python-2.7, 64-bit, nltk

I'm new to Python and NLTK. I've been trying to find a solution to my problem but have not found one yet and was hoping someone could help me.

I'm currently running 64bit Windows 8. I've followed the instruction in the NLTK website (http://www.nltk.org/install.html). I might have installed a 64bit version Python in the first place but have removed it and reinstall 32bit version Python. Now I'm having the following problem:

```
Python 2.7.9 (default, Dec 10 2014, 12:24:55) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> import nltk

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import nltk
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\__init__.py", line 117, in <module>
from nltk.align import *
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\align\__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
from nltk.align.ibm1 import IBMModel1
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\align\ibm1.py", line 18, in <module>
    from nltk.corpus import comtrans
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\corpus\__init__.py", line 64, in <module>
    from nltk.tokenize import RegexpTokenizer
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\__init__.py", line 62, in <module>
    from nltk.data              import load
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\data.py", line 74, in <module>
    if os.path.expanduser('~/') != '~/':
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ntpath.py", line 310, in expanduser
    return userhome + path[i:]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xac in position 9: ordinal not in range(128)
>>>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Help please, anyone?

Comment: Problem solved after changing to Python 3.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve this by changing my operating system locale for non-Unicode programs:

1 – Go to Control Panel

2 – Click “Clock, Language and Region”

3 – Click “Regional and Language Options”

4 – Go under “Administrative” tab

5 – current system locale (for non-Unicode) is displayed, to change it click “Change system locale”

6 – Then just choose English! After a reboot, done!

Comment: Restarting after the change took a while but i helped. Thanks!