# NLTK Import Error (Windows)

Tags: python, windows, unicode, import, nltk

IPython throws an error when trying to import NLTK. The error is:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe3 in position 11: ordinal not in range(128)

No code-sharing is needed, as it crashes on the first line (import). I have already tried to change from 64 to 32bit and still getting the same error.

I found one thread reporting this very same problem ([NLTK import error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28509263/nltk-import-error)) but it did not help me because I can't upgrade my Python Version to avoid compatibility problems (it is a group project).

I have already checked that the module is currently installed and have also already tried to reinstall it.

Any ideas? Thank you in advance for the atention.

Comment: Your ANSI codepage is probably 1252, in which `'\xe3'` is `u'\N{latin small letter a with tilde}'`, from your name "João". The simplest solution is to change your user name (and thus your profile directory) to one that only uses ASCII characters. ;-)

Comment: Due to Microssoft Accounts problems, I cannot change my Username. D you know any other solution that may resolve the problem? Thank you for trying to help.

Comment: They're using `unicode_literals` in [`nltk.data`](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/data.py#L33), which means the failing call effectively is `os.path.expanduser(u'~/')`. That forces the interpreter to decode the ANSI byte string from the environment variable using the default encoding, which is ASCII. There are ways to change the default encoding, but I don't recommend that.

Comment: I'd wrap `ntpath.expanduser` with a function that works around the problem. Save and call the original as `ntpath._expanduser`. In the wrapper, when the `path` argument is `unicode`, encode it as `'mbcs'` and then decode the result as `'mbcs'`. But allow an instance of `str` to pass through without modification.